# How to use an Android Library with custom layout in CodenameOne native interface?

Tags: android, codenameone

I am trying to integrate the [AndroidPDFViewer by barteksc](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) into my CodenameOne app using a native interface to add this code. I would like to create the PDFView, return it as a View in the native interface, and use it as a PeerComponent in my project. When I made the Java interface file in my regular CN1 code, my return value was PeerComponent and the native interface generator set the return value of that interface method as `View`.

I have used this library before while creating a native Android app in Android Studio and it works great. However, my CN1 project can't seem to find the xml layout for the `PDFView`, which would normally would be in an Android xml file. This is what the xml would look like, as per the GitHub page:

```
<com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
    android:id="@+id/pdfView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Using CN1 build hints, I added the following to the .properties file:

`codename1.arg.android.cusom_layout1= <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView android:id="@+id/pdfView"      android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>`

In my Android native interface, I added the following code (with the appropriate imports, no errors there):

```
 LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    View theview = li.inflate(R.layout.cusom_layout1, null, false);
   PDFView pdfView = (PDFView)theview.findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
   /*(PDFView)findViewById(R.id.pdfView);*/
    if (param1) {
        pdfView.fromBytes(param)
                .pages(1)
                .onError(onErrorListener)
                .onTap(onTapListener)
                .enableSwipe(false)
                .enableDoubletap(false)
                .load();
    } else {
        pdfView.fromBytes(param)
                .onError(onErrorListener)
                .onTap(onTapListener)
                .enableSwipe(false)
                .enableDoubletap(false)
                .load();
    } 
return (View)pdfView;
```

I got this error; it looks like it can't find the layout but I don't know how to connect the layout with the format for initializing the PDFView in the Java code (according to the docs, it needs to reference the View ID).

`Exception: android.view.InflateException - Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class PDFView`

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create the `PDFView` manually via code instead of using the XML layout?

Notice that every XML layout is just a view hierarchy same as the component hierarchy and you can just create an instance of the `PDFView` with the context taken from `AndroidNativeUtil`.

Comment: Thank you. I added the xml manually, like you said using XmlPullParser.No errors there, but it doesn't show in the app. However, that's a different issue/question to solve. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't say you should use Xml parsing or the XML at all? I said use the `PDFView` manually. Literally `new PDFView(activity)`.

Comment: But the constructor doesn't accept `activity` as a parameter, on its own. It's `new PDFView(activity, attributeSet)`. That's why I tried to inflate a layout instead and use `findViewById`. This is where I'm having trouble.

Comment: I would just edit that file and add a second constructor https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer/blob/master/android-pdf-viewer/src/main/java/com/github/barteksc/pdfviewer/PDFView.java it's an omission that they didn't include it.